# jquery php mysql html passing value on one page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im curious, if the value of `<p class="myclass"></p>` assign by jquery using `$('.myclass').text('txtvalue');` can be fetch using PHP script? example. like i want to fetch the assign value of jquery without using jquery post, ajax to pass value in PHP because im do this with only one page.

here my code:

```
    <p class='myclass'></p>
    <?php
       $a = strip_tags("<p>","<p class='myclass'></p>"); 
       echo $a; 
    // the result is 100; but its dismase like im printing "<p class='myclass'></p>"; i im trying to do is to get exactly the value of "<p class='myclass'></p>". because the value of that, i will use to query in mysql id.

           //it is impossible to me to do this?...
?>
```

```
<script>
     $('.myclass').text('100');
</script>
```

Comment: Theoretically I assume you can post to same page , later check the post , parse the same page and you should be able to do so ...But seems over complicated for such a task. much easier to just echo the value in the jQuery ...

Comment: i just try to post on same page, but it only return the value in jquery response, no request, post, and or get in php to fetch the value. i want to fetch the assign value of jquery in php because i need to query mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be done.

PHP runs server-side and generates your HTML, including any Javascripts with jquery in it. When it's done, Javascript gets to work, client-side. The only way to get something back into PHP is to send it to the server by posting it, ajax, or redirection.